# How can I suppress the prompt to "Unify Duplicated Vertices" when opening several meshes from regular GUI

Tags: vertices, meshlab, unify

I have a folder with hundreds of STL meshes and I want to merge them in meshlab using the flatten command.

I´m using the regular GUI and when I go to file open and pick all these STL files, I´m prompted for each and every file if I want to "Unify Duplicated Vertices".

As I have hundreds of them, this is unacceptable. Is there any way to configure the software to apply my "yes" to all models it opens?

Tks!

Comment: Yep.. I'm not going to use this application because of this behaviour.  It's extremely annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49952824/8634018) to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48662309/meshlab-how-to-turn-off-the-unify-duplicated-vertices-prompt/49952824) which duplicates yours: user suprjami said

> You can't. I provided feedback to the developers via Facebook that they should make this an option.

Answer (score 2):

It is in the upcoming MeshLab version

You can try (at your own risk :) ) the prerelease builds; you can found them here:

- dmg for osx: https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab/releases
- portable version for win https://ci.appveyor.com/project/cignoni/meshlab/build/artifacts