# Meshlab: How to turn off the "Unify Duplicated Vertices" prompt?

Tags: meshlab, stl-format

every time I open an STL file with Meshlab, a window pops up and asks, whether I want to "Unify Duplicated Vertices". It is sort of annoying that I always have to press the "OK" button. How can I tell Meshlab that it should always unify them without asking?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems that my question is a duplicate of [this (unanswered) one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43219065/how-can-i-suppress-the-prompt-to-unify-duplicated-vertices-when-opening-severa?rq=1) Does it mean I should close it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I suppress the prompt to "Unify Duplicated Vertices" when opening several meshes from regular GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43219065/how-can-i-suppress-the-prompt-to-unify-duplicated-vertices-when-opening-severa)

Comment: @Ian: yes, it is. I had already stated so in my comment from 2018-02-28 (when I found that out). So what is the etiquette in such cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. I provided feedback to the developers via Facebook that they should make this an option.

Answer (score 1):

It is in the upcoming MeshLab version

You can try (at your own risk :) ) the prerelease builds; you can found them here:

- dmg for osx: https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab/releases
- portable version for win https://ci.appveyor.com/project/cignoni/meshlab/build/artifacts

[image]

Comment: This option does not seem to be available in v1.3.2_64bit and it does not seem to be available in version 2020_12 either.